# Return dictionary keys based on list integer value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following:

```
my_list = ["7777777", "888888", "99999"]
my_dict = {21058199: '500', 7777777: '500', 21058199: '500'}
```

I am trying to create a new dictionary which will include the dictionary value (from the original dictionary) that matches the list entry to the dictionary key (in the original dictionary)

```
for k in my_dict.keys():
  if k in my_list:
      new_dict.append(k)

print(new_dict)
```

should return

```
7777777: '500'
```

But I'm returning an empty set.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: just change k to str(k) .. you are comparing string with integer ..

Comment: derp.  ty everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictionary comprehension would provide you what you need.

- You need to make sure the types agree (`int` vs. `str`)
- Unless the list is significantly longer than the dict, it will be much more efficient to iterate over the list and check that key is in the dict than the other way around.

E.g.:

```
In []:
new_dict = {k: my_dict[k] for k in map(int, my_list) if k in my_dict}
print(new_dict)

Out[]:
{7777777: '500'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this :

```
my_list = ["7777777", "888888", "99999"]
my_dict = {21058199: '500', 7777777: '500', 21058199: '500'}

new_dict = {k:my_dict[k] for k in my_dict.keys() if str(k) in my_list}
print(new_dict)

# {7777777: '500'}
```

**Update:**

You can also do this with [project](http://funcy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/colls.html#project) function from [funcy](https://github.com/Suor/funcy) library.

```
from funcy import project

new_dict = project(my_dict, map(int, my_list))
print(new_dict)
```

Comment: Just a couple of minor points: `in` for lists is much more expensive (`O(n)`) than `in` on a dictionary (or set) (`O(1)`). You don't need to call `.keys()` to iterate over the keys of a `dict` - that is the default, e.g. `for k in my_dict:`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `int()` the iterator.

```
my_list = ["7777777", "888888", "99999"]
my_dict = {21058199: '500', 7777777: '500', 21058199: '500'}

for l_i in my_list:
    if l_i in my_dict:
        print(my_dict[int(l_i)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary keys are of the type 'Int', while your list items are strings. You need to convert one into the other.

for example:

```
new_dict = {}
for k in my_dict.keys():
    if str(k) in my_list:
        new_dict[k] = my_dict[k]
```

Note that you cannot use `.append()` to add key-value pairs to a dictionary.